# Set of generators of the commutator subgroup of a surface group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Good morning,

I am having a hard time trying to describe the commutator subgroup of a surface group. Namely, if $S$ is a compact orientable surface and $G$ its fundamental subgroup, let's recall that $G$ is given by the following presentation $ \langle a_1, b_1, ..., a_g, b_g \ | \ \prod_{1\leq i \leq g}{[a_i,bi]} =1 \rangle$. Its commutator subgroup is an infinite rank free group. Can one give a set of generator of this subgroup ? Or even better, could one make such a set free ?

I would be grateful for any hint or reference !

Selim

Comment: Just a guess for the genus 2 surface: Take a simple loop $c$ which separates $S$ in two one-holed tori. Then $c$ is clearly in the commutator subgroup of $G$. Now, consider the orbit of $c$ under the entire group $Aut(G)$. The result, I think, is a generating set for the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What you say is right and can be extended in the general case, since $G$ is a free group, $Aut(G)$ acts transitively on free set of generator. However, I'm searching for an explicit description of a set of generator, which could be found using your method if one is able to describe $Aut(G)$ or the orbit of an element through its action.

Comment: See this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184176/commutator-subgroup-of-a-free-group?rq=1 for the answer in the case of commutator subgroup of the free group. The same method should work for surface groups.

Comment: @SelimGhazouani, $\;G\;$ as given by you *can't* be a free group since it is defined by means of non-trivial relations.

Comment: Now asked on MathOF https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296006/generators-for-commutator-subgroup-of-surface-group

Comment: @DonAntonio, this comment exhibits some confusion. First, the question doesn't claim that $G$ is free, only that its commutator subgroup is free (which is true). Second, there are plenty of presentations of free groups with non-trivial relations.

Comment: @HJRW Yes indeed, your comment shows some confusion. First, my above comment was in response to the comment by Selim above, where he claims $\;G\;$ , **not** $\;G'\;$ , is free. That's what I was addressing. Second. If the presentation includes non-trivial relations on **all** the generators then the group cannot be free *on those generators*.

Comment: @DonAntonio -- apologies, I see what you mean about Selim's comment, although I think  a more generous interpretation is that Selim's comment contains a typo: I suspect he wrote $G$ when he meant $G'$.  In any case, your second assertion (a group defined by a non-trivial relation is free) is incorrect, and it seems misleading to leave it uncorrected.

Comment: @HJRW No, the second comment isn't incorrect since I was referring to what the OP wrote on those generators. And if there was some space to make a more generous interpretation of what Slim wrote, then I think **he** should have said something about it, or better: edited his question to correct what you think is a typo...observe that in that comment he writes twice $\;G\;$ (also in the Aut($G$) thing).

Comment: @DonAntonio, OK, I'm glad you knew what you meant. It wasn't what you wrote, so it wasn't clear to me, and presumably it might not be to other readers. As you say, Selim can explain his comment if he chooses.