# Decomposing elements of the commutator subgroup into simple commutators

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a free non-commutative group with generator set $X$. We know that the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ has a basis consisting of simple commutators of the form $[g_1,g_2]$, where the elements $g_1,g_2 \in G$ have specific form (details can be found here
[Commutator subgroup of a free group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184176/commutator-subgroup-of-a-free-group) )

Is there an algorithmic way of decomposing a given element of $[G,G]$ into a product of basis elements?

Stephan

Comment: Here is an example:  $x_1 . x_2 . x_3^{-1}.x_4.x_1^{-1}.x_5^{-1}.x_3.x_2^{-1}.x_1^{-1}.x^4^{-1}.x_5$ . It is certainly an element of $[G,G]$ but it is not a product of simple commutators. It can be decomposed into a product of simple commutators in many ways. Moreover, I am more interested in how to decompose it a product of simple commutators from the basis i linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the Nielsen-Schreier theorem is basically an algorithm once you manage to find a Schreier transversal for your subgroup. In the case of the derived subgroup the transversal is very easy to find (e.g. it is described in several other discussions here) and the decomposition simply follows the proof of the theorem.